# Нужно написать игру Ним с двумя кучами и Двумя игроками (второй игрок это ИИ)

Tags: python

Игра ним для двух игроков с двумя кучами и без ограничения на количество забираемых камней.
Напишите программу с «искусственным интеллектом» (ИИ), которая играет против пользователя и выигрывает, если может. Исходное количество камней в кучах задаёт пользователь, программа всегда ходит первой. Выигрывает забравший последний камень, и при окончании игры нужно объявить победителя.
Алгоритм игры выглядит следующим образом:

Сначала пользователь вводит количества камней в кучах (натуральные числа, каждое на новой строке).
Затем первый ход делает программа и выводит через пробел четыре числа: из какой кучи взяты камни; сколько камней взято; сколько камней осталось в кучах, сначала в первой, затем во второй.
Затем ход делает пользователь: вводит на отдельных строках номер кучи и количество камней, которые он хочет взять.
Если ход некорректный, например, пользователь пытается взять камней больше, чем есть в куче, программа должна вывести: Некорректный ход: <куча> <кол-во камней> и ожидать нового ввода пользователя.
После каждого корректного хода игрока или ИИ нужно выводить четыре числа, как и после первого хода ИИ.
Если выигрывает игрок, то надо вывести фразу: Вы выиграли!, а если ИИ – фразу: ИИ выиграл!
Все сообщения программы должны строго соответствовать условию.

Формат ввода
Для старта игры вводятся два натуральных числа.
Пример диалога игры:

10
10
2 1 10 9
1
15
Некорректный ход: 1 15
2
10
Некорректный ход: 2 10
2
7
2 7 10 2
1 8 2 2
2
1
2 1 2 1
1 1 1 1
1
1
1 1 0 1
2 1 0 0
ИИ выиграл!

Примечания
Обратите внимание, что ИИ в выводе не показывает получаемые данные от игрока.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
while a != 0 or b != 0:

    if a == 0:
        print(1, b, 0, 0)
        b -= b

    elif b == 0:
        print(1, a, 0, 0)
        a -= a

    elif a > 0:
        if a != 1:
            print(1, a - 1, a - (a - 1), b)
            a -= (a - 1)
        else:
            print(1, 1, 0, b)
            a -= 1
    elif b > 0:
        if b != 1:
            print(1, b - 1, a, b - (b - 1))
            b -= (b - 1)
        else:
            print(1, 1, a, 0)
            b -= 1

    if a == 0 and b == 0:
        print("ИИ выиграл!")

    while True:
        c = int(input())
        d = int(input())
        if c == 1:
            if 0 < d <= a:
                break
            else:
                print("Некорректный ход:", c, d)
                continue
        elif c == 2:
            if 0 < d <= b:
                break
            else:
                print("Некорректный ход:", c, d)
                continue
        else:
            print("Некорректный ход:", c, d)
            continue

    if c == 1:
        a -= d
    else:
        b -= d
    print(c, d, a, b)
    if a == 0 and b == 0:
        print("Вы выиграли!")
```

Я так сделал но проверка пишет что в некоторых случаях "ИИ должен был выиграть, а проиграл". Нужно написать другой алгоритм ИИ. Я дохринилиард раз пробовал переделывать алгоритм но как видите не получилось(

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде выигрышная стратегия в данном случае - это на свой ход всегда уравнивать  количество камней в кучках. Таким образом если после игрока в одной из кучек остаётся 1 камень, то ИИ сравняв кучки, в обоих оставит по одному, что означает выигрыш на свой следующий ход. А если игрок опустошит одну из кучек, то выигрыш сразу. Все остальные случаи сводятся к походу на комбинацию 1:1. Единственное, когда с таким ИИ игрок может выиграть - это когда изначально кучки равны, ИИ вынужден их разбалансировать, а игрок станет исполнять стратегию ИИ, т.е. сам будет выравнивать кучки (и не дай бог ему хоть раз ошибиться :)).

Примерно так:

```
# функция взятия amount камней из кучки what
def take(what, amount):
    pile[what] -= amount
    print(what, amount, pile[1], pile[2])

# в словаре хранятся кучки под ключами 1 и 2
pile = {1: int(input()), 
        2: int(input())}

while True:
    if pile[1] > pile[2]:   # берём из первой кучки чтобы сравнять кучки
        take(1, pile[1] - pile[2])
    elif pile[1] < pile[2]: # берём из второй кучки чтобы сравнять кучки
        take(2, pile[2] - pile[1])
    else: # кучки уже равны - ничего не остаётся как взять камень из одной из них (лучше брать по минимуму, чтобы измотать игрока - вдруг он где ошибётся, и ИИ перехватит инициативу :))
        take(1, 1)

    if pile[1] == 0 and pile[2] == 0:
        print("ИИ выиграл!")
        break

    while True:
        p = int(input())
        n = int(input())
        if (p == 1 or p == 2) and 0 < n <= pile[p]:
            break
        print("Некорректный ход:", p, n)

    take(p, n)
    if pile[1] == 0 and pile[2] == 0:
        print("Вы выиграли!")
        break
```

Comment: Есть Ним-3 v2.0 там всё также только 3 кучи, я попробовал сделать так чтобы первым ходом ИИ забирал всю 1 кучу, а дальше всё идёт по тому же принципу. Но проверка снова пишет что в в каком-то случае "ИИ должен был выиграть, а проиграл" можешь помочь пожалуйста https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1344392/Помощь-в-решении-задачи-Ним-3-v2-0

Comment: Вам же там привели решение.

Comment: Нет, оно не правильное