# Помощь в решении задачи Ним-3 v2.0

Tags: python

Игра ним для двух игроков с тремя кучами и без ограничения на количество забираемых камней.
Напишите программу с «искусственным интеллектом» (ИИ), которая играет против пользователя и выигрывает, если может. Исходное количество камней в кучах задаёт пользователь, программа всегда ходит первой. Выигрывает забравший последний камень, и при окончании игры нужно объявить победителя.
Алгоритм игры выглядит следующим образом:

Сначала пользователь вводит количества камней в кучах (натуральные числа, каждое на новой строке).
Затем первый ход делает программа и выводит через пробел пять чисел: из какой кучи взяты камни; сколько камней взято; сколько камней осталось в кучах, сначала в первой, затем во второй, а потом и в третьей
Затем ход делает пользователь: вводит на отдельных строках номер кучи и количество камней, которые он хочет взять.
Если ход некорректный, например, пользователь пытается взять камней больше, чем есть в куче, программа должна вывести: Некорректный ход: <куча> <кол-во камней> и ожидать нового ввода пользователя.
После каждого корректного хода игрока или ИИ нужно выводить пять чисел, как и после первого хода ИИ.
Если выигрывает игрок, то надо вывести фразу: Вы выиграли!, а если ИИ – фразу: ИИ выиграл!
Все сообщения программы должны строго соответствовать условию.

Формат ввода
Для старта игры вводятся три натуральных числа.
Пример диалога игры:

2
2
2
1 2 0 2 2
1
2
Некорректный ход: 1 2
1
0
Некорректный ход: 1 0
2
1
2 1 0 1 2
3 1 0 1 1
2
1
2 1 0 0 1
3 1 0 0 0
ИИ выиграл!

я написал вот такой код:

```
    def take(what, amount):
    pile[what] -= amount
    print(what, amount, pile[1], pile[2], pile[3])


pile = {1: int(input()),
        2: int(input()),
        3: int(input())}


while True:
    if pile[1] > 0:
        take(1, pile[1])
    elif pile[2] > pile[3]:
        take(2, pile[2] - pile[3])
    elif pile[2] < pile[3]:
        take(3, pile[3] - pile[2])
    else:
        take(3, 1)

    if pile[1] == 0 and pile[2] == 0 and pile[3] == 0:
        print("ИИ выиграл!")
        break

    while True:
        p = int(input())
        n = int(input())
        if (p == 1 or p == 2 or p == 3) and 0 < n <= pile[p]:
            break
        print("Некорректный ход:", p, n)

    take(p, n)
    if pile[1] == 0 and pile[2] == 0 and pile[3] == 0:
        print("Вы выиграли!")
        break
```

но в каком-то случае проверка пишет что "ИИ должен был выиграть, а проиграл"

Comment: `"ИИ должен был выиграть, а проиграл"` — пусть улучшают свой и.и., чтобы не проигрывал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def step(k):
    s = 0
    for h in k:
        s ^= h
    if s == 0:
        return k.index(max(k)), 1
    for i in range(len(k)):
        if 0 <= k[i] ^ s < k[i]:
            return i, k[i] - (k[i] ^ s)
    return k.index(max(k)), 1


cnt = 3
k, s = [0] + [int(input()) for _ in range(cnt)], True
while sum(k):
    s = not s
    if s:
        while True:
            h, n = int(input()), int(input())
            if 0 < h <= cnt and 0 < n <= k[h]:
                break
            print('Некорректный ход:', h, n)
    else:
        h, n = step(k)
    k[h] -= n
    print(h, n, *k[1:])
print('Вы выиграли!' if s else 'ИИ выиграл!')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

А разве логика игры НИМ не такая:

```
nim = pile[1] ^ pile[2] ^ pile[3]

index = 0
value = 0
for i in pile:
    if pile[i] >= nim and pile[i] > value:
        value = pile[i]
        index = i
        
take(index, value)
```

Ну или если хочется покороче:

```
nim = pile[1] ^ pile[2] ^ pile[3]

move = max((pile[i], i) for i in pile if pile[i] >= nim)

take(move[1], move[0])
```